# Running a program and providing input

Tags: bash, command-line, input, programming

I have a program that runs from the command line. As soon as it runs, it asks for a text value and expects the return key to be pressed after that.

Is that possible to create a bash script that runs that program, wait a little bit for the prompt to appear (lets say 2 seconds) and then provide the text and the enter key?

EDIT:

I have created this script with expect but it is not working:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout 15
set user "myusername"
set server "x.x.x.x"

spawn ssh -l $user -p AAAA $server
expect "myusername@x.x.x.x's password: "
send "the password\r"
```

where AAAA is the port and x.x.x.x the IP.

when I run this script it finishes almost immediately and nothing happens.

Comment: Have you looked at `expect`?  This is the sort of task it was made for

Comment: I have edited my question to show the script I have created using expect. First time I hear about expect. I was "expecting" the script to work, but it is not.

Comment: Try ending the `send` command with `\r` to "press enter"

Comment: sorry about that, I forgot to type `\r` on the question. The script has `\r` and is not working.

Comment: Is there any compelling reason why you can't use certificate-base authentication and dispense with the need for a password and its attendant complexity entirely?

Comment: Are you sure your expect pattern matches exactly (including case) what you're getting back?

Comment: certificate-base authentication = no, because my boss give me that order and yes, the case matches completely.

Comment: I don't use expect much, but if my expect script wasn't working, I'd look at using the method here: http://www.cotse.com/dlf/man/expect/exp_internal.htm to find out what was going wrong.

Comment: how do I use that inside the bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working now, but I changed the script to:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout 15
set user "myusername"
set server "x.x.x.x"

spawn ssh -l $user -p AAAA $server
expect "myusername@x.x.x.x's password: " { send "the password\r" }
interact
```